# Eliminar un objeto de un array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array que se llama `hoteList`:

```js
let hoteList = [
  { name: 'hotel riviera', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel paris', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel london', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel rome', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 }
];
```

Quiero eliminar el hotel `london`, así que el resultado final debería ser esto:

```js
let hoteList = [
  { name: 'hotel riviera', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel paris', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel rome', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 }
];
```

Quiero también mandar un mensaje al usuario tipo asi:

```js
alert("el hotel london se ha eliminado correctamente");
```

He intentado con `splice()`, `indexOf()`, `remove()` y `filter()`, pero ninguna me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Aca te dejo una posible solucion utilizando el filter para mostrar todos menos el que elijas no mostrar:

```
let hotels = [
  {
   'name': 'hotel riviera','numberOfRooms': 28,'numberOfFloors': 2,'surfaceOfHotel': 1200
  },
  {
    'name': 'hotel paris','numberOfRooms': 30,'numberOfFloors': 3,'surfaceOfHotel': 1300
  },
  {
    'name': 'hotel london ','numberOfRooms': 32,'numberOfFloors': 4,'surfaceOfHotel': 1400
  }
  ]

hotels = hotels.filter(h => h.name !== 'hotel riviera');
console.log(hotels)
```

Resultado:

```
0: (4) {name: "hotel paris", numberOfRooms:...}
1: (4) {name: "hotel london ", numberOfRoom...}
```

Tambien te diria que seria mejor si agregaras un `id` por cada hotel y filtres en base a ese `id`

Comment: no me funciona porque no se como filtra lo que puso el usuario

Comment: a que te refieres con que no sabes que puso el usuario? podrias compartir mas al respecto para poder ayudarte, tal vez puedas pone el codigo en Visual Studio Code online y compartir en enlace. Saludos.

Comment: no se como se comparte esto

Comment: Lo de compaortir usando visual studio puedes buscarlo en google, podrias añadir como estas filtrando para poder ayudarte, si el usuario selecciona un hotel tendrias que filtrar usando ese dato pero no muestras como lo esta haciendo, agregalo a la pregunta para poder darte mas detale de como hacerlo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Creamos una función que reciba como parámetro el nombre del hotel para eliminarlo.
- Hacemos un `find()` para buscar el elemento en el valor de su atributo `name` sea el parámetro de la función (si el parámetro es `hotel london`, devuelvo ese elemento porque si existe).
- Luego verificamos si existe ese elemento. Si existe, alteramos el array original por el array que nos devuelve el `filter()`, quien se encarga de devolver todos los elementos de `hoteList` **menos** el elemento que tenga como valor (del atributo `name`) el parámetro de la función. Si no existe, solo retornamos un mensaje.

**Demo:**

```js
let hoteList = [
  { name: 'hotel riviera', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel paris', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel london', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel rome', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 }
];

function eliminarHotel(nombreHotel) {
  // Primero intento buscar el elemento (que es un objeto) del array en el que su valor del atributo "name"
  // sea el argumento de la función. 
  const hotelEliminado = hoteList.find(hotel => hotel.name === nombreHotel);

  // Si se encontró el elemento...
  if (hotelEliminado) {
    // Reemplazo el array original por el array que nos devuelve el "filter()", quien se encarga de devolver
    // los elementos MENOS el elemento en el que su valor del atributo "name" sea el argumento de la función...
    hoteList = hoteList.filter(hotel => hotel.name !== nombreHotel);

    // Y devuelvo un mensaje y el nuevo array del "filter()".
    console.log(`El hotel ${nombreHotel} se ha eliminado correctamente.`);
    console.log(`Esta es la nueva lista de hoteles: `, hoteList);
  }
  // De lo contrario, quiere decir que el elemento no existe y devuelve otro mensaje.
  else {
    console.log(`No se encontró ningún hotel con el nombre ${nombreHotel}.`);
  }
};

eliminarHotel('hotel london');
```

```js
let hoteList = [
  { name: 'hotel riviera', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel paris', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel london', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 },
  { name: 'hotel rome', numberOfRooms: 28, numberOfFloors: 2, surfaceOfHotel: 1200 }
];

function eliminarHotel(nombreHotel) {
  const hotelEliminado = hoteList.find(hotel => hotel.name === nombreHotel);

  if (hotelEliminado) {
    hoteList = hoteList.filter(hotel => hotel.name !== nombreHotel);

    console.log(`El hotel ${nombreHotel} se ha eliminado correctamente.`);
    console.log(`Esta es la nueva lista de hoteles: `, hoteList);
  } else {
    console.log(`No se encontró ningún hotel con el nombre ${nombreHotel}.`);
  }
};

eliminarHotel('hotel london');
```